# Where can I change mail daemon address on a Exim4 server?

Tags: exim4

I cannot find where can I set the mailer-daemon address for bouncy mail, now it is set to Mailer-Daemon@mydomain1.com and I would like to change it to Mailer-Daemon@mydomain2.com, but looking into all exim files I did not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option you need is `dsn_from`:

```
dsn_from = Mail Delivery System <Mailer-Daemon@$qualify_domain>
```

See https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-main_configuration.html

Answer (score 2):

In your conf file you should just find/add `bounce_sender_authentication` and set like:
`bounce_sender_authentication = mailer-daemon@mydomain2.com`

Example on exim github page - line 15: https://github.com/Exim/exim/blob/master/test/confs/3412

Comment: I tried to add this line in a main section configuration file but it doesn't work for me....

Comment: Where shoud I put this command in a multi-file configuration?